# Is there a way to prevent a 500 status code when using error.tsx?

Tags: next.js

Currently in a Next 14 app, I have a app structure similar to below:

```
- app
   - lorem
      - page.tsx
      - error.tsx
   - layout.tsx
```

Within the logic of page.tsx, I'm intentionally throwing an error if certain conditions fail. I would then expect the error.tsx to be able to catch and display that error message. However, the page still returns a 500 error status code when this error occurs.

Is there a way to properly catch this error, so that the rest of the app continues as normal, and just the error message is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Well no, not directly since the `error.js` file convention is meant to return a 500 status code to indicate a faulty server response to crawlers etc. But take the following example for a server component with a error state using conditional rendering:

```
interface Props {
  id: string | number;
}

export default async function MyComponent({ id }: Props): JSX.Element {
  // fetching your data or whatever may fail
  const response = await fetch(`https://example.com/api/users/${id}`, {
    cache: "no-store",
  });

  // using a eager return for the error
  if (!response.ok) {
    return <p>Oh no a error!</p>
  }

  // parse body after `ok` check
  const user = await response.json();

  return <p>My name is {user.name}</p>;
}
```

I strongly recommend only to do this if the error does not heavily influence the overall page content since crawlers would not know if `Oh no a error!` is a error state rather than the page content.

Comment: That would mean every Server Component would need to handle and display it's own errors though, whereas the benefit of error.tsx is that it automatically catches what has happened further down the chain.

Comment: Exactly! That is indeed what the `error.js` convention is for.

Comment: But it doesn't work like that. It's not catching the error, otherwise the page wouldn't result in a 500.

Comment: @rwacarter A 500 status code indicates a server error. This is the semantically correct approach by Next.js if for whatever reason this does not fit your needs, use a [Error Boundary](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#catching-rendering-errors-with-an-error-boundary).

Comment: A 500 status code indicates an *unexpected* server error. I'm talking about errors that are a result of incorrect user input or similar, 422s etc. Using an Error Boundary is exactly what Next is doing when you use an error.js

Comment: Yes, while that might be true the usage of an error boundary as such does not produce a 500 status code. Just trying to help here.